# Rails model generator - from existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, plugins

Is there any working automatic model generator for creating a model from existing database?

Something like symfony's task [symfony doctrine:build-model](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks#chapter_16_sub_doctrine_build_model).
I found just Dr Nic’s magic model generator but it doesn't work with rails 2.3+. Please do not recommend Dr Nic's magic models. That's not what I want.

I don't believe that there is nothing else for such a common task.

EDIT: I don't want to generate just empty models. I want to also automatically generate associations and validations.

Answer (score 5):

Hey there. This is quite a simple procedure to do;

1. Modify your_project/config/database.yml with connection params so that it connects up to your existing database.
2. For each table you wish to turn into a model type the following:

> script/generate model tablename

Comment: be careful of one thing:
If your table name is 'items', camelcase and singularize it to 'Item' when running the script/generate command.
another eg: 'new_users' => 'NewUser'

Comment: Thanks for response. But this is not what I want. This doesn't do the same as I mentioned. If I use this, it will generate just empty model. I want something that will automatically generate associations and validations, because the information about it is there, in the database. Like "Dr Nic’s magic model generator" (wich, as I said, is not working for rails 2.3+)